# Why is silhouette_score always returning 0 on this Iris dataset?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, k-means

I was testing out some features of Scikitlearn, and although their [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html) works fine for me and returns a number for silhouette, when I do the equivalent on the Iris dataset it shows a clustering, and then always outputs 0 for the silhouette average:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = datasets.load_iris()

print(dir(iris))
print(iris.DESCR)
#print(iris.data[:,1:3]) second and third part of each, columns.
X = iris.data[:, 1:3]

for i in range(2,11):
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=i, random_state=0)
    model.fit(X)
    #print(model.labels_) #Different number for each "cluster" found.
    centroids = model.cluster_centers_
    #Separate xs [:, 0], ys [:,1] and scatter plot:
    plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker='x', s=170, zorder=10, c='m')
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=model.labels_)
    #print(plt.scatter.__doc__) # <--- what are the arguments?
    plt.xlabel("Sepal width")
    plt.ylabel("Petal length")
    print(X)
    print(model.labels_)
    print('For %d clusters the average silhouette score is %d' % (i, silhouette_score(X, model.labels_)))
    plt.show()
```

Why is it doing this as it appears to be giving it a similar X array and labels as the Scikit example?

Comment: you are casting from `float` to `int` (`%d`), use `%f` at your print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching your print statement to either:

```
print('For %f clusters the average silhouette score is %f' % (i, silhouette_score(X, model.labels_)))
```

Or:

```
print('For {} clusters the average silhouette score is {}'.format(i, silhouette_score(X, model.labels_)))
```

Or:

```
print(f"For {i} clusters the average silhouette score is {silhouette_score(X, model.labels_)}")
```

...fixes the issue.

As stated by @shahaf in the comments, you are casting from float to int (%d).